# How can I effectively document a database?

Tags: mysql, database, documentation, standards

I am developing a database that organizes scientific data from my group and diverse experiments reported in the literature, (my background is in science rather than project management or programming).

I currently have three documentation documents for:

1. end users of data
2. data enter-ers
3. developers (e.g. myself and my successor)

Other than following the users guides and descriptions from other databases, are there any best-practices I should follow, perhaps a latex template, or a mysqldump option that will automatically do some of the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doxygen supports SQL. I would export the DDL SQL statements, document them with Doxygen notation and export it to HTML / PDF / whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there were a standard solution, but industry practice is ad hoc at best.

In MySQL, be sure to fill in the comment fields when creating tables and fields.  If you use MySQL administrator, it makes it easy to manage, but that's most useful for developers to directly use.  It can be used as the basis for expansion for the other categories of readers.